# How to update specific column in a table vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created a database and it contains a column name Cust_NColor. The user is able to select color for Name textbox using a Color dialog box which appears when a button is clicked. I want the selected color value to be updated to the database in Cust_NColor column and also want to update a single specific column using TableAdapterManager or please suggest an alternative way to update specific column.

Comment: Please remove the lines "Please answer as soon as possible" and "Thanks!" because it doesn't add any value to the question itself.

Comment: You can try this https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/308055/how-to-update-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-sqldataadapter-object

Comment: hi Broick, welcome to stackoverflow, i hope you can share with us a [mcve] to try.

Comment: @SurajKumar Thanks for it....It worked

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection()
Dim CustomersDataSet As New DataSet()
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim dr As DataRow        
Dim DAUpdateCmd As SqlCommand


cn.ConnectionString = "Server=.;Database=northwind;UID=sa;PWD=;"
cn.Open()

da = New SqlDataAdapter("select * from CustTest order by CustId", cn)

'Initialize the SqlCommand object that will be used as the DataAdapter's UpdateCommand.
'Note that the WHERE clause uses only the CustId field to locate the record that is to be updated.

DAUpdateCmd = New SqlCommand("Update CustTest set CustName = @pCustName where CustId = @pCustId", da.SelectCommand.Connection)


'Create and append the parameters for the Update command.

DAUpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pCustName", SqlDbType.VarChar))
DAUpdateCmd.Parameters("@pCustName").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current
DAUpdateCmd.Parameters("@pCustName").SourceColumn = "CustName"

DAUpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pCustId", SqlDbType.Int))
DAUpdateCmd.Parameters("@pCustId").SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original
DAUpdateCmd.Parameters("@pCustId").SourceColumn = "CustId"


'Assign the SqlCommand to the UpdateCommand property of the SqlDataAdapter.
da.UpdateCommand = DAUpdateCmd        

da.Fill(CustomersDataSet, "Customers")        

Console.WriteLine("Customer Name before Update : " & CustomersDataSet.Tables("Customers").Rows(0)("CustName"))

CustomersDataSet.Tables("Customers").Rows(0)("CustName") = "Jack"
da.Update(CustomersDataSet, "Customers")        

Console.WriteLine("Customer Name updated successfully")

cn.Close()
Console.ReadLine()
```

You can learn in details [**here**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/308055/how-to-update-a-sql-server-database-by-using-the-sqldataadapter-object).